# ByRef Argument Type Mismatch while calling function

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing small VBA code, and getting error `ByRef Argument Type Mismatch` when function `LoopThroughNamesAndPopulateValues()` is called by `Main()`

```
Sub Main()
    Call LoopThroughQuoteNamesAndPopulateValues("Sheet2", 1, 1)
End Sub

Sub LoopThroughQuoteNamesAndPopulateValues(ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal row As Integer, ByVal column As Integer)
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)

    For i = row To 10000
        If sheet.Cells(i, column).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            Call Finder_Get_Query(sheetName, i, column)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You're aware that both row and column are reserved words in VBA...?

Comment: ohh I didnt, actually I do, but getting back to VBA after long. But still it does not work. Changes `row` to `rowNum` and `column` to `columnNum`

Comment: You must have pasted the wrong function name or calling code line. The `Call` does not match the `Sub`. (and the row/rw parameter should be a Long, probably column/cl as well)

Comment: sorry that happened while writing stackoverflow question. Fixed. Actually am debuging it, execution jumps at function name and shows error.

Comment: Can you step through the code and see if it gets to "Finder_Get_Query" (maybe that's where the parameters are invalid)

Comment: Actually I don't think either are reserved words. First, Does your module have "Option Explicit" at the top? If not, add it and compile. My guess is this won't compile because i is not declared. Maybe not the issue though, unless Finder_Get_Query is choking on i. Second) put an error handler in Finder_Get_Query and one in LoopThroughNamesAndPopulateValues and see which one catches your error.

Comment: your code as is works for me until i get to Finder_Get_Query (indicating the problem is that procedure

Comment: Tonns thank you. Added Option Explicit. That forced me to explicitly define variables in `Finder_Get_Query` and `LoopThroughQuoteNamesAndPopulateValues`. Then it all worked. For me, it was not getting inside 'LoopThroughQuoteNamesAndPopulateValues` while debugging

Comment: @DonJewett please add as answer

Answer (score 0):

**Option Explicit**: Add "Option Explicit" to the top of the module and compile. My guess is this code won't compile because i is not declared. Maybe not the issue though, unless Finder_Get_Query is choking on i.

**Error Handling**: put an error handler in Finder_Get_Query and one in LoopThroughNamesAndPopulateValues and see which one catches your error. This will help you narrow down your code.

Many simple problems can be solved by following these two steps. Here is my preferred error handler, which is handy for debugging because it allows you to resume at runtime if you want:

```
Sub SampleErrorHandler()

    On Error GoTo EH

    'code

    GoTo FINISH

EH:
    With Err
        MsgBox "Error:" & vbTab & .Number & vbCrLf _
            & "Source" & vbTab & .Source & vbCrLf _
            & .Description
    End With

    'for debugging purposes
    Debug.Assert 0
    GoTo FINISH
    Resume

FINISH:

    'clean up, release resources

End Sub
```